# How to receive Twilio SMS to command Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, twilio

Receiving Twilio SMS Commands on Raspberry Pi

I signed up for Twilio https://www.twilio.com and got a phone number that I 
can use to send SMS messages from the Raspberry Pi and I can also receive
SMS message on my Raspberry Pi.

I have put together a script on using a received SMS message to command 
an action on the Raspberry Pi.  It works, but I would like suggestions for
cleaning it up.

Particularly - when I try to retrieve the SMS message, Twilio dumps the whole 
lot of messages the account ever received and I need to filter them to 
only the most recent message.  See below, I have set an 'if' function to 
check the time the message was sent (in seconds) against the current time 
(in seconds) less '18009' which allow only those sent in the last few (~8)
seconds to appear.  This seems too kludgy - I would like a better way.

Thanks,

{

```
import datetime
import time
import os
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
import email.utils

twilio_account_sid = "GetSIDFromTwilioAccount"
twilio_auth_token = "GetTokenFromTwilioAccount"
sTwilioNumber = "+TwilioPhone#"
client  = TwilioRestClient(twilio_account_sid, twilio_auth_token)

while (True):
    for message in client.messages.list():

        # select only messages where time now less time sent
        if (time.mktime(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timetuple())-18009) \
        < email.utils.mktime_tz(email.utils.parsedate_tz(message.date_sent)):

            # if message from my phone
            if message.from_ == "+MyPhone#":

                if message.body == 'command1':
                    os.system('Command1.sh')
                    time.sleep(7)

                if message.body == 'command2':
                    os.system('command2.sh')
                    time.sleep(7)

                etc,
                etc,
```

}

Comment: What I ended up doing was just client.messages.list()[0] to get the latest input in the list

Answer (score 1):

Twilio can listen to incoming messages and call a rest api/ servlet/ web service etc hosted on ur server. So every time you get a message on the twilio number , this api gets called and then you can automate what you want to do. So rather than you ponging the twilio server if you have your own web server on ur raspberry pi, twilio can relay the message when it gets an sms.

Hope I am able to answer your question. I have integrated my web app with twilio on google App engine. I am going to buy a raspberry pi 2 very soon and learning python at the moment. I chanced upon your query and thought of sharing whatever little I know.